# Initialize dynamic array in structure

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have a C++ structure shapes like this block:

```
typedef struct _VisibleString
{ 
    uint8_t size;
    unsigned char text[size]; 
}VisibleString, *LPVisibleString;

typedef struct _Device
{
    uint16_t deviceType; 
    uint8_t powerSupplyStatus;  
    VisibleString  manufacturer;
    VisibleString  model;
    VisibleString  revision;
    VisibleString  deviceTag;
    VisibleString  serialNo;
}Device, *LPDevice;
uint16_t numberOfDevices;
Device devicesList[numberOfDevices];
```

I am thinking of making content in the text is depend on the size. However, I keep receiving error of:

```
error: invalid use of non-static data member
```

It seems that I cannot declare a the text array with dynamic size. Is there any way to solve this problem? I am trying to receive information and separate it depend on its size.

Comment: How about `unsigned char *text;`, and later on `text = new unsigned char[size]`? That's what people usually mean when they say "dynamic".

Comment: I am sorry if I have a different intention when I wrote about the "dynamic". if you mean that I have to redeclare the text outside of the struct, I think it is hard to do because the mentioned struct will be called by another struct. I will update my complete structure code.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "redeclare the text". Can you give an example of what you want to do?

Comment: I want to separate some bulk information, received from tcp into a specific location by utilizing the struct. For example in the visible string: if in the size variable being stored value of 4, then the content that I need to save inside the text=4 (text[4]). I hope this can help you understand my intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you're trying to do, so I'll try to guess.

You have

```
Device devicesList[numberOfDevices];
```

and suppose you want to put data into the `manufacturer` field of `devicesList[2]`. You have the data:

```
uint8_t data_size;
unsigned char data[30];
```

where the value of `data_size` is 5, and the first 5 elements of `data` are "Zeiss".

If you define the structs this way:

```
struct VisibleString
{ 
  uint8_t size;
  unsigned char *text; 
};
```

you can fill in the `manufacturer` field this way:

```
devicesList[2].manufacturer.size = data_size;
devicesList[2].manufacturer.text = new unsigned char[data_size];
for(uint8_t k=0; k<data_size; ++k)
  devicesList[2].manufacturer.text[k] = data[k];
```

and when you no longer need that string, you should free the memory:

```
delete [] devicesList[2].manufacturer.text;
```

**That's the simple, crude way. The cleaner, more sophisticated way is to use member functions and STL containers.** We can show you how to do that whenever you like.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment. It looks simpler in this way.

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like C code. If you're really using C++, then I recommend the C++ way using `std::string` instead of trying to dynamically do it yourself; let `std::string` take care of that for you.

Also don't declare structs using the typedef keyword unless you have to; that's the old C way.

```
struct VisibleString
{ 
    uint8_t size;
    std::string text; 
};

typedef VisibleString* LPVisibleString;
```

In fact, you could simply use text itself since text.length() or text.capacity() will give you one of the sizes that you want.

To answer your original question doing allocation yourself, I recommend @Beta's way:

```
struct VisibleString
{ 
    uint8_t size;
    unsigned char* text; 
};
```

Later on, you'll need to allocate the memory and also be sure to clean up after yourself:

```
VisibleString s;
s.size = 20;
s.text = new unsigned char[size];

try
{
   ...

   delete[] s.text;
}
catch (...)
{
   delete[] s.text;
}
```